# Python 3.5 error with init function not taking enough arguments

Tags: python

I'm having an issue creating a simple class on codewars. I am receiving the following error:

> `Traceback: in TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)`

I realize I supplied the init function with two parameters along with the `self` parameter. When I create my object from my class, I am supplying two strings for the two parameters. I'm not sure what else I am doing wrong. Is it the codewars browser? I appreciate any assistance. Please see below:

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, name, other_name):
        self.name = name
        self.other_name = other_name

    def greet(self):
        return "Hi {0}, my name is {1}".format(self.other_name, self.name)

xy = Person("Raiden", "Donald")
xy.greet()
```

I have checked the other questions on this subject and it always seems that the issue is that the person calling the class is not supplying it with the necessary parameters. I am doing that, however. I appreciate any assistance.

EDIT************

It is worth noting that I can produce the above code in my regular python IDLE. I have this exact same code in the codewars window. Hers is the original codewars question: 
***Correct this code, so that the greet function returns the expected value.***

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

  def greet(self, other_name):
    return "Hi {0}, my name is {1}".format(other_name, name)
```

Comment: Can't reproduce on Python 3.5.1

Comment: Which codewars problem are you doing. Can you post the link? Also, are you sure that is all the code you have in the Codewars editor window?

Comment: I have edited my original comment to include the original codewars start code plus the question. It is also worth noting that I can reproduce the original code I posted in my IDLE with no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Codewars problem is giving you code you need to correct. When you submit it, it runs against a series of unittests that are defined by the question creator. Here is the original code:

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

  def greet(self, other_name):
    return "Hi {0}, my name is {1}".format(other_name, name)
```

The error you are getting when submitting this code is:

```
Traceback:
   in 
   in greet
NameError: global name 'name' is not defined
```

So, with that error message, by analyzing the code you will notice that in the `greet` method, you actually are trying to use a variable `name` that was in fact never defined!

That is actually the error you need to be fixing. You were trying to add an extra variable in your **init**. So, what was happening, was the unittests that were running against your code, were expecting only a single value to be passed to your **init**.

The solution to this problem, was to simply change the `name` in the `greet` method to `self.name`, so that it uses the instance attribute. So your final code is pretty much:

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

  def greet(self, other_name):
    return "Hi {0}, my name is {1}".format(other_name, self.name)
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. I would have never caught that. I would have continued to try and complicate the matter by adding more code and contemplating banging my keyboard. Thank you sir for the thorough and detailed information. Much appreciated :)

Comment: @raidboss You're very welcome. Have fun with Codewars. It's great. If this helped you, please make sure you upvote and accept the answer. It helps the next individual seeking similar help to know that this was helpful. Cheers and good luck!

Comment: my bad, I checked both since they both technically answered the question. I was unaware only one check could apply. I marked your answer since that was a great and thorough explanation. Hope others can benefit from this. Thanks again!

Comment: @raidboss Thanks a lot. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Codewars is running test cases on your code to see if you succeeded in fixing the given code. All of these test cases assume that the `Person` constructor takes one positional argument. Since you changed the signature of `Person.__init__` to require two positional argument, each test case will throw the reported `TypeError`.

To correct the supplied code, think about whether there is a local variable named `name` in the `greet` method.